# 17.10: How do I set to always install pending software updates when shutting down?

Tags: gnome, 17.10, shutdown, update-manager, wayland

Interestingly, when I check for software updates, none are found. But every time that I shut the computer down, there is a checkbox to install pending software updates. Why waste my time clicking this when either it could only appear when updates are available, or it could be enabled by default in settings?

Comment: I want to know too(18.04).